# Testflight SDK and iOS Simulator - how to use?

Tags: ios, testing, logging, testflight

I'm a bit puzzled how I'm supposed to use Testflight's SDK jn combination with the iOS Simulator.

Let's say I'm starting to integrate Testflight into my project and want to test it on the Simulator. Obviously I will not get any remote logs or checkpoint information because my project hasn't been uploaded (although I'm using the correct team token).

But if I upload the project first, it says that it isn't using Testflight SDK - which is of course correct, so I won't get anything either.

So I'm facing a chicken-egg problem here or do I misunderstand something?

Is Testflight working at all with Simulator?

Comment: can't you just upload a version of the app, then run in the simulator or the device after that?

Answer (score -8, accepted):

TestFlight works fine with the simulator. Although in our case the user is not identified, as  you don't have a UDID on the simulator. But all the logs and checkpoints show up with an 'Anonymous' user.

So, I would just take the plunge and upload your project to TestFlight. You don't have to invite testers to use it.

Comment: If it works for you, could you explain how? My simulator gets stuck when installing the certificate, and Testflight support says it´s not working in the simulator.

Comment: Yeah how do you get it installed on the simulator?

Comment: You can't run the app store in the simulator, so you can't install TestFlight from the app store.  This isn't really a complete answer; all of the commenters are left wondering.

Answer (score 7):

The TestFlight SDK app is designed to run on Arm Architecture on device. The simulator is not considered a valid device so it will not work for testing apps made available on Test Flight. You also won't be able to install the Test Flight profiles on the emulator (the accounts with permission to use the app on Test Flight).

A workaround is to run the code locally in Xcode (assuming you have the code) and then compile the app and build for the iOS simulator.

In summary TestFlight is designed to work with real devices.

Other workarounds;

- Fully publish the app with a login requirement on the landing page, get it approved to the store and run it on any device including the emulator.
- Get beta testers online to tryout the app for you from sites like: https://betafamily.com/ or Upwork, Fiverr etc.
- Or just buy a bunch of cheap old iPhones to use for testing. (Always better to test on old devices for backward compatibility :))

Comment: why isn't this the preferred answer?