# Testflight on the iOS Simulator?

Tags: ios, ios-simulator, testflight

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Testflight SDK and iOS Simulator - how to use?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10380331/testflight-sdk-and-ios-simulator-how-to-use)

I´m struggling to use Testflight on the iOS Simulator. Is this even possible? It seems like the Simulator can´t install the certificate. Is there any other way to use Testflight on the Simulator?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10380331/testflight-sdk-and-ios-simulator-how-to-use

Comment: Thanks, but that previous question didn´t give me a hint on how to do it.