# How to deal with checkpoints in TestFlight when using iOS simulator?

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios-simulator, testflight

I need to provide some analytics about my app by means of `TestFlight SDK`. I have created an application in my `TestFlight` account and successfully integrated the SDK into my project. Now i put a simple checkpoint into the code:

```
[TestFlight passCheckpoint:@"TEST_CHECKPOINT"];
```

and try it in simulator. I can see the following in Xcode console:

```
TestFlight: Checkpoint Passed - TEST_CHECKPOINT
```

which makes me think this part has been done ok. But i cannot find a message from this checkpoint in the `TestFlight` account. This [simple article](http://help.testflightapp.com/customer/portal/articles/829889-how-do-checkpoints-work-) states that i can find checkpoints info on `Checkpoints` tab but where the hack it is? I can't find it.

An undertaken search has quickly led me to [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10380331/testflight-sdk-and-ios-simulator-how-to-use). But it has just messed things up even more for me. Seems like (i'm not sure if i really need it) i should upload my project to `TestFlight`. But how do i do that? I can't find it nowhere.

So can anyone shed a light onto the issue and explain what exactly should one do in order to achieve the following - pass a checkpoint (particularly in simulator) and see that it has successfully arrived to the `TestFlight` account? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is important to not what you will never see any activity into testflight until you push the app into testflight.
It apply to remote logging, crash report, checkpoint and so on...

First you need to export your app into an ipa on your hard drive.

Follow the steps:
[image]

Your organizer will popup. Click the button "Distribute..."

Then sign your app with **adhoc** certificate (google to find how to do it)
[image]

Save on your hard drive "YOUR_APP.ipa"

Now upload your ipa into testflight:
https://testflightapp.com/dashboard/builds/add/

You will need a account to upload on it of course.
Now you need to download the ipa from testflight into your iPhone...
http://blog.testflightapp.com/post/1346521917/register-devices

**Edit:**
It look like actually you can get some information from your simulator. But I guess you have to upload the App at least one time on Testflight.

I'm just getting tiny information from my simulator into testflight so I still recommend to deploy on a real device.
[image]

If you don't upload to

Comment: so i CAN'T use TestFlight in simulator?

Comment: @AndreyChernukha no you can't. Sorry about that.